# Activating WCF service from MSMQ via WAS not in the default website

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, was

We are hosting a WCF service that listens to a queue in MSMQ with the same name. When we browse to the service's url, the messages in the queue get picked up.

When the application pool recycles, the Windows Activation Service should take over and activate the service based on the name of the queue.

This does not seem to happen, and the problem might be that the service is not hosted in the default site (and the WAS does not know in which site to look for the service).

Is there any way to get the WAS to work with a different site than the default one? Every setup I find online seems to work with the default website.